# function to add input values in array in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to build a function to add elements (taken from input fields) in array:

```
function printPeople(idUser){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var surname = $('#surname').val();
    var age = $('#age').val();

    var people = []; 


    people.push({
                    "id": idUser,
                    "name": name,
                    "surname": surname,
                    "age": age
});
```

Everytime I press button "subscribe" I need to add new information in the array, my goal is obtain an array like this:

```
[{
"id": id,
"nome": name,
"cognome": surname,
"age": age
},
{
"id": id,
"nome": name,
"cognome": surname,
"age": age
}, etc]
```

In my case I created an empty array and then I add the elements, but everytime I press the button, array becomes empty again...the array doesn't exist outside of the function, so I need to create it at the beginning (and so the array will be empty everytime I call the function..). Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Because your array is in the function scope, so every time it creates a new array. Just declare your array outside of the function.

```
 var people = []; 

function printPeople(idUser){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var surname = $('#surname').val();
    var age = $('#age').val();

    people.push({
                    "id": idUser,
                    "name": name,
                    "surname": surname,
                    "age": age
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function scope recreates a new array when you call the function, so the best way to handle this will be to declare the function outside

```
var people = [];

function printPeople(idUser){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var surname = $('#surname').val();
    var age = $('#age').val();   

    people.push({
                    "id": idUser,
                    "name": name,
                    "surname": surname,
                    "age": age
   });
}
```

Also you can save to local storage so when you refresh you get the same array back.

**To Save**: `localStorage.setItem('peopleArray', JSON.stringify(people));`

**To Get**: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('peopleArray'));`